# Am I close to getting an Electorate Badge? How do I check?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, badges

I have ~700 votes total atm and I know a majority of them are on questions. Is there a way to find out close or far I am from getting this badge? A search here turns up a couple of questions on electorate badges but none of them seem to answer this specific question.

Also I tried this [stack-exchange query here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/470/electorate-badge-progress) but it doesn't appear to work. It shows I only have 5 votes! That can't be right.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That query is broken, because (as [drachenstern said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73751/am-i-close-to-getting-an-electorate-badge-how-do-i-check/73752#73752)) the user ID isn't included for most votes to avoid revealing who voted for what. The one exception is favoriting a question (which is stored as a type of vote in the database); if you run [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/17516/) you'll see that all your votes have VoteTypeId 5, which corresponds to a favorited question (you apparently had five favorited questions as of the last data dump).

As for your actual question, as far as I know there is no good way to see your Electorate progress. On [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/234175?tab=stats) you can see your total vote count (you have 688 upvotes and 12 downvotes at the moment), but not a breakdown of how many of those votes were on questions

Comment: See, more eloquent ;)

Comment: Well that's unfortunate, it would have been nice if there was a way to find out.

Answer (score 4):

There's a reason not all votes are shown in the database (think mining to find out who voted how on what and retaliation) so I don't think it'll give you most of the votes.

I'm sure someone here will post a more elegant answer and prove that this should've been a comment, but for now, I'll put it as an answer for you ;)